# How to upload files using PrimeReact FileUpload Component

Tags: reactjs, spring, web-applications, primereact

I am a React/Spring beginner and I dont know how to make a Fileupload with Primereact.
Their Documentation says following (https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/fileupload):

> FileUpload requires a url property as the upload target and a name to identify the files at backend.

`<FileUpload name="demo" url="./upload"></FileUpload>`

But it neither say how do I fetch the data, how I access the "demo" in the backend, nor what kind of reponse I get.

Can anyone help me please? I have already searched the web but did not find anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```js
<FileUpload name="invoice"
    accept="image/*"
    customUpload={true}
    uploadHandler={invoiceUploadHandler}
    mode="basic"
    auto={true}
    chooseLabel="Upload invoice"/>
```

```js
const invoiceUploadHandler = ({files}) => {
    const [file] = files;
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        uploadInvoice(e.target.result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

Send your request like this

```js
const uploadInvoice = async (invoiceFile) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('invoiceFile', invoiceFile);

    const response = await fetch(`orders/${orderId}/uploadInvoiceFile`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        },
    );
};
```

**Important:** Do not set any `Content-Type` header! This will be done automatically.